# How can I echo specific line from a text area using php

Tags: php, html

I am collecting html text area data to echo in php.I am able to select all data using

```
$devices = explode("\n", $_POST['devs']);
foreach($devices as $device)
echo $device;
```

and I am able to select only the first line using:

```
$first_line = strstr(($_POST['devs']), "\n", true);
echo $first_line;
```

But How can I echo  specific lines ? say line 2 or 4 from text area ?

Comment: `echo "Second line: \n", $devices[1], "\nFourth line: \n", $devices[3];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage:

```
getLines(YOUR POST, START LINE, END LINE(optional));
```

**With return array:**

```
function getLines($text, $start, $end = false)
{
    $devices = explode("\n", $text);
    $append  = "My device is ";

    $output = array();
    foreach ($devices as $key => $line)
    {
        if ($key+1 < $start) continue;
        if ($end && $key+1 > $end) break;
        $output[] = $append.$line;
    }
    return $output;
}

$array = getLines($_POST['devs'], 2);
var_dump($array);
```

**With echo string:**

```
function getLines($text, $start, $end = false)
{
    $devices = explode("\n", $text);
    $append  = "My device is ";

    $output = "";
    foreach ($devices as $key => $line)
    {
        if ($key+1 < $start) continue;
        if ($end && $key+1 > $end) break;
        $output .= $append.$line."<br />";
    }
    return $output;
}

echo getLines($_POST['devs'], 2);
```

Comment: how i can select a range using this ? from second line to last ? where the line count can not be predicted

Comment: @acr array indexes starting with `0`. Its mean, for example: getting line 3 you have to use `echo $devices[2];`

Comment: @acr for using range, you can use `foreach`

Comment: @ Bora         I got it.my question is suppose I have 10 lines and I want to display line 2 to last line 10. In above example I have  mention each line by line like $devices[1] to $devices[9]. But in my case I am not sure how many lines will be there.that depends upon how many lines a visitor enter to my text area. so what I want is I need line 2 to line n to be echoed where n is my last line number. something foreach function

Comment: @acr wait a minute. You want output all lines as echo string or array?

Comment: @ Bora          array but not all lines. from second to last

Comment: @  Bora         : it worked..I need to edit it more..I have to add extra text with these lines.currently it taking as a single value with all lines. I have to change it. something like this 'my device is $devices[2]' , 'my device is $devices[3]. with current code it will show like 'my device is $devices[2] $devices[3]'. I am working on this...

Comment: @ Bora          will be able to add  `my device is`  text along with this command  `echo getLines($_POST['devs'], 2);`  ?

Comment: @ Bora   : I believe we cant add  `$output .= $line.$append"<br />";` like as a suffix. I see at end of `$line` it is breaking line.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code snippet is already creating an array of lines via the [explode](http://www.php.net/explode) function.

As such, to output the 2nd and 4th lines, you can simply use:

```
$devices = explode("\n", $_POST['devs']);
echo $devices[1];
echo $devices[3];
```

If you're new to PHP (I'm guessing this is the case due to the nature of your question), it should be noted that like many programming languages, arrays are indexed from zero, hence line 2 is [1](http://www.php.net/explode), line 4 is [3], etc.

**UPDATE**

To access the penultimate (i.e.: 2nd to last) line, you could use:

```
echo $devices[count($devices) - 2];
```

What we're doing here is getting the number of elements in the array (via [count](http://www.php.net/count)) and then subtracting two to fetch the second last element. (As we need to subtract one to deal with the fact that arrays are indexed from zero.)

Comment: @ middaparka   : Thanks for making it clear.(I am new to php). suppose, if I want to select second line to the last line, how we will mention the last one ? I mean we really dont know how many lines are there, but need to select from the second to last..

Comment: @ middaparka : one last question. how we can select a range of devices ? example from 2 to last ?. I would like to know how can I call them together.(similar way we use foreach function, without mentioning each with  '$devices[n]' ).

Comment: @acr The easiest way would be to use a normal `for` loop rather than a foreach I'd have thought.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
$nth_line = explode("\n", $_POST['devs'])[n];
```

where n is you line no.

the explode() returns an array then you can select each element by basic array operation
further readings http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Note that this syntax is only supported in PHP 5.4+

Comment: php 4 and above supports explode.

Comment: I'm referring to accessing index `n` on the same line. PHP 5.3 and below does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

because `$devices` is an array after exploding it, you can treat each line by it's index. Reminder that arrays are zero-index based so 1 starts at 0.

```
$devices = explode('\n', $_POST['devs']);

// line 1
echo $devices[0];

// line 2
echo $devices[1];

// line 4
echo $devices[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use split:

```
$lines = split("\n", $_POST['devs']);

echo $lines[3];  //4th line
```

See documentation http://php.net/manual/es/function.split.php

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at array operations in PHP. Since `$devices` is an array you can select an element by its index like this: `$devices[1]` for second element, `$devices[2]` for third etc.

Answer (score -1):

Lookup your syntax on php.net. It is

```
$devices = explode(";", "aap;noot;mies");
print_r($devices);
   foreach ($devices as $key => $value) {
     echo "<br>nr.$key=" .  $devices[$key];
   }
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer further?